# Angular Material DatePicker Storing Previous day in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, angular, date

I am new to both angular and Java 8 features. But, currently I am working on a project where I  am using a DatePicker from angular material and that date I am trying to store the MySQL database, but it is storing the previous date of selected date. I am passing LocalDateTime from front end and storing ZonedDateTime in database by giving ZoneId "Asia/Kolkata". It was storing the current date when I used to run my server on localhost in INDIA but the server is running on US and I am facing this problem.
Any Help?

Backend code/logic:

`/*here, hostDto.getDate() provide Object of 'LocalDateTime' in this format 2018-09-05T18:30:00.000Z*/
ZonedDateTime localdate = hostDto.getDate().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
host.setDate(localdate);
/*host.setDate() accept ZONEDDateTime*/`

Comment: can you share some code that  you have tried??

Answer (score 0):

It's a timezone issue. Please refer to this. They have solved the issue.  https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2628

Comment: Ya that is exactly the same issue I am facing but I culdn't get proper solution there

Answer (score 0):

Had similar trouble with postgres. What I did is I am formatting the date type without any time zone and time, just plain date before storing to db. Possibly not ideal but works for me.

The date in db is defined as date with no timezone.

Comment: can you just help me with the code snippet , how to format date of format 2018-09-05T18:30:00.000Z

Comment: I don't know about your structure on server etc. but I am using node.js and am formatting date using moment: `moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`. Mind you I am using Postgres, YMMV